# Choose elements from two numpy arrays at random

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to merge two numpy arrays together by choosing elements from each at random. 
Say I have two arrays of equal length `x` and `y` as follows:

```
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10, 20)
```

and a mask `r`:

```
r = np.random.choice([True, False], 10)
```

Then is there any way to select elements from `x` where `r` is `True` and from `y` where `r` is `False`?

I don't have to use the mask approach, but I need something fast as `x` and `y` will be much longer than 10 in reality so ideally no looping involved.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
z = y.copy()
z[r] = x[r]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a one-liner using the `np.where(<condition>, <where_true>, <where_false>)` syntax of [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
z = np.where(r, x, y)
```