# Mixing Two Numpy Arrays Randomly

Tags: arrays, numpy, random, mixing, crossover

This is my first question on Stack Overflow, so bear with me. Let's say I have two arrays of the same shape, `X` and `Y`

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array(([0, 0],
              [0, 0]), dtype=float)

X = np.array(([1, 1],
              [1, 1]), dtype=float)
```

I want to create a function `mix_arrays(X, Y)` that will mix the arrays together randomly, like so:

```
def mix_arrays(array_0, array_1)
    # magic
    new_array =  # ...
    return new_array
```

Here's what it could return:

```
mix_arrays(X, Y)
# Could Return:
# [[0, 1], 
#  [1, 1]]
# or:
# [[1, 0], 
#  [0, 1]]
# or:
# [[0, 0], 
#  [1, 1]]
```

Basically, the for each element in `new_array`, the element has a 50% chance being from `array_0`, and a 50% chance being from `array_1`

I'm sure this question already exists, but I couldn't find it on stack overflow. Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235758/choose-elements-from-two-numpy-arrays-at-random Does this help?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `np.where`

```
def random_mix(X, Y):
    choice = np.random.randint(2, size = X.size).reshape(X.shape).astype(bool)
    return np.where(choice, X, Y)
```